# celery not all tasks in a group are executed

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I have simple celery case:

```
@task()
def my_task1(index):
    log.info(index)

@task()
def my_task2():
    tasks=[my_task1.si(1), my_task1.si(2), my_task1.si(3), my_task1.si(4)]
    group(*tasks)()
```

When I run `my_task2`, I only see tasks with integers 2 and 4 in celery console. I want to run them all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - I had another celery running...